# How to get username or email from objectidentifier or nameidentifier from Api?

Tags: rest, api, azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I am getting signedInUserID in Web Api and want to fetch username or other details from below code

```
string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

What are the ways we can fetch user details or email from signedInUserID.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch email in web api 2 which is secured by WAAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895329/how-to-fetch-email-in-web-api-2-which-is-secured-by-waad)

Comment: As we discussed , you are using client credential flow to get the access token , please use  authorization code flow which includes user's basic information in access token .